# Rerun runnerclass is running before the original runner class in cucumber

Tags: gradle, cucumber, cucumber-junit, cucumber-serenity

```
CucumberSerenityBDDAPIAutoRunner
CucumberSerenityBDDUIAutoRunner
CucumberSerenityBDDUIReRunner
```

Are my runner classes lying in one folder. I have chosen alphabetical increasing order to run the rerunner class at the end.

```java
@RunWith(CucumberWithSerenity.class)

@CucumberOptions(features= “src/test/resources/features/ui/“, glue = “com.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.features”, plugin = {“pretty”,“rerun:target/failedrerun.txt”}, monochrome = true, tags = “@envr=stagging and @UI”)

public class CucumberSerenityBDDUIAutoRunner {
    @WithTag(“envr:stagging”)
    public void run_stagging_tests(){}

    @WithTag(“envr:prod”)
    public void run_production_tests(){}
}
```

```java
@RunWith(CucumberWithSerenity.class)

@CucumberOptions(features= {“@target/failedrerun.txt”}, glue = “com.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.features”, plugin = “pretty”, monochrome = true, tags = “@envr=stagging and @UI”)

public class CucumberSerenityBDDUIReRunner {
    @WithTag(“envr:stagging”)
    public void run_stagging_tests(){}

    @WithTag(“envr:prod”)
    public void run_production_tests(){}
}
```

These are my two concreate runner classes.

Error which I am receing from the gradle run is below since the rerunner is running before the original runner:

```
com.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.features.CucumberSerenityBDDUIReRunner > initializationError FAILED
    io.cucumber.core.exception.CucumberException: Failed to parse ‘target/failedrerun.txt’
```

How can i choose the correct sequence?

Comment: Can you please [edit] your markup to add syntax highlighting to your code blocks? You can see [/editing-help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) for how to do so. (Note: please do not replace your code block with a screenshot of your IDE. [That would be worse](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541))

Comment: Tests should be independent. You're asking for trouble if your tests depend on each other.

Comment: Tests are independent only but the returner should run at the end,that is the prime objective which is to run for the failed test cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround I have created a seperate gradle task to run the rerunner classes at the end and removed the CucumberSerenityBDDUIReRunner class from source.

```
configurations {
    cucumberRuntime {
        extendsFrom implementation
    }
}

task reRun(type: JavaExec, dependsOn:testClasses) {
            systemProperties System.getProperties()
            systemProperty "cucumber.options", System.getProperty("cucumber.options")

            mainClass = "net.serenitybdd.cucumber.cli.Main"
            classpath = configurations.cucumberRuntime + sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output
            args += [
                    '--plugin', 'pretty',
                    '@target/failedrerun.txt',
                    '--glue', 'com.abc.def.ijk.features']
}
```

Now I run `gradle --info clean test reRun  aggregate -Denvironment='stagging' -Dtags='envr:stagging' -Dcucumber.options='--tags @envr=stagging'`  from commandLine.

This time the

```
CucumberSerenityBDDAPIAutoRunner 
and 
CucumberSerenityBDDUIAutoRunner
```

Classes as a part of ***test*** task and rerun will run the failed test cases link generated in `@target/failedrerun.txt` file.

Serenity report only takes the latest test case run in account( ***i.e***
the rerun one if it has run as a part of reRun task)

***P.S:*** we can put after reRun task in ***build.gradle*** file

```
tasks.test {
    finalizedBy reRun
}
```

then the old `gradle --info clean test aggregate -Denvironment='stagging' -Dtags='envr:stagging' -Dcucumber.options='--tags @envr=stagging'` command will also work.